# Objects with user-defined hash

Tags: python, oop

Assume I have a class A with a overriden hash method that returns some user-defined integer:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self,hash):
      self.hash = hash

   def __hash__(self):
      return self.hash

   def __cmp__(self,other):
      return cmp(self.hash,other.hash)
```

Now, at any given point in time, I'd like to have only one object with the same hash, so I maintain a set `s` that contains such objects of class A. My problem is the following:

```
s = {A(1234)} 
a = A(1234)

if a in s:
   # then assign the corresponding object in set s to a
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a valid definition of [`__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__).

Comment: You're right, indeed. I fixed that.

Comment: yet another typo sorry, i fixed that again

Comment: `if a in s`, then the corresponding object in set `s` _is_ `a`, so there's no need to assign `a` to itself.

Comment: @martineau: not sure about that! Doesn't `if a in s` make a comparison based on hashes?

Comment: @Greg: True. In that case use a dictionary whose keys and values are the same object i.e. `d[a] = a` since there's no way to access individual members of a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a set, use a dictionary (which is also a set, in a sense).

```
objects = {}
a = A(1234)
if a.hash in objects:
    a = objects[a.hash]
objects[a.hash] = a
```

Comment: Alternatively, `objects.get(a.hash(), a)` or `setdefault` to set it as well.

Comment: You don't need to be using `a.hash`, just `a` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a singleton implemented as a class variable:

```
>>> class A:
    HASH = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.hash = A.HASH
        A.HASH += 1
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.hash
    def __cmp__(self,other):
        return cmp(self.hash, other.hash)


>>> a = A()
>>> a.__hash__()
0
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a2.__hash__()
1
>>>
```

Since it's increased each time you instanciate a new object, you're sure not to have twice the same value (this might not be thread-safe, though).

**EDIT**: if the hash value is computed, this solution is not valid since it starts from 0 arbitrarily...

Answer (score 0):

I used the following mechanism to make sure that no duplicate object was ever created. This is a mixture of Emmanuel's and Jordan's answers.

```
class A(object):
   __singletons__ = dict()

   def __new__(cls,hash):
      if hash not in cls.__singletons__.keys():
         cls.__singletons__[hash] = super(A,cls).__new__(cls)

      return cls.__singletons__[hash]

   def __init__(self,hash):
      self.hash = hash

   def __hash__(self):
      return self.hash

   def __cmp__(self,other):
      return cmp(self.hash,other.hash)
```